# Get current time zone (Django)

Tags: python, django, time, timezone, pytz

I currently have `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'` set in my settings.

In my `DebitCard` model `expiration_date` field, I store the date as a unixtime. For instance 01/10/2020 @11:25pm (UTC) is `1578698708`.

The problem is:

Let's say the `expiration_date` is **January 15th, 2010 at 00:00** or (1263513600).

I want to block users from making a transaction when the **current time** is greater than the **expiration_date**.

However, if the user is in LA (8 hours before UTC), the **current_time** will be off by 8 hours.

Question:

How do I grab the user's current time wherever they are (not just in LA)? Because I want to grab this time and compare it to their debit card `expiration_date`

Comment: From my understanding, when your server receive the request, there will be a time stamp, just compare it with expiration_date and you do not necessarily need to know user's timezone.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP
from .utils import GeoTimeZoneReader


  g = GeoIP()  # get user ip
  g.city(request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
  g.city('74.125.79.147') # get city 
to get timezone 

  data = GeoIP().city('74.125.79.147')

  # Get Time Zone
  db = GeoTimeZoneReader()
  db.get_timezone(data['country_code'], data['region'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that your code is using UTC time to do the comparison, use `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`

For example, try running the following in python or in your manage.py shell:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

You can compare the output of that to a simple `datetime.datetime.now()`. If the computer you're using is not in UTC, now() and utcnow() will be different.